# how can i filter data in CGridView depending on table flag

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and am unable to filter data in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView depending on the active flag field of my DB table.
I want to show only data's where active flag is 0.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'member-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'f_name',
    'l_name',
    'dob',
    'gender',
    'location',
    'email',
    'active',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model's search() method you need to customize the [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria).

You need to add:

```
$criteria->compare('active', 1);
```

If you want to go more advanced, you could create a [Named Scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) and use that when you define your ActiveDataProvider in the search() method like this:

```
new CActiveDataProvider(Member::model()->active(),.....);
```

the scope would be:

```
public function active()
{
    return array(
            'condition'=>$this->getTableAlias(false, false).'.active =1',
    );
}
```